# laravel how to handle empty json results set from a query

Tags: json, laravel

I am very new to the laravel framework and i have what it seems to be a simple question. I have a query like so

```
 $query['query2']= DB::connection('test')->select(
"select * from cities");
 ...
 ...
 echo json_encode($q);
```

Sometimes this particular query returns an empty result set. 
How do I handle this? Lets say I want to add my own json response when its empty.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
 $dataToSend = $q->get(); // $q being your query

 if($dataToSend->isEmpty())
 {
   echo json_encode(['something'=>'else']);
 }
 else
 {
   echo json_encode($dataToSend);
 }
```

Or in a shorter fashion

```
 $dataToSend = $q->get(); // $q being your query

 echo json_encode($dataToSend->isEmpty()? ['something'=>'else'] : $dataToSend);
```